# How to use image_tag with srcset and active storage variant?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage, srcset

I would like to use image_tag srcset attributes with active storage variants

```
    <%= image_tag(@assoc.photo,
    srcset:[
      [@assoc.photo.variant(resize: "600x600"), "1024w"],
      [@assoc.photo.variant(resize: "800x800"), "1980w"]
      ],
      sizes: "100vw") %>
```

The first line return: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer.

What's wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did a method for resize the photos :

```
  def photos_variants(photo, width, height)
    variation = ActiveStorage::Variation.new(Uploads.resize_to_fill(width: width, height: height, blob: photo.blob))
    ActiveStorage::Variant.new(photo.blob, variation)
  end
```

and I call this method in my srcset tag :

```
<%= image_tag(@assoc.photo,
srcset:[
  [url_for(@assoc.photos_variants(@assoc.photo, 400, 300)), "512w"],
  [url_for(@assoc.photos_variants(@assoc.photo, 600, 450)), "768w"],
  [url_for(@assoc.photos_variants(@assoc.photo, 800, 600)), "1024w"],
  [url_for(@assoc.photos_variants(@assoc.photo, 1200, 900)), "1980w"]
  ],
  sizes: "100vw") %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping `@assoc.photo.variant(resize: "600x600")` in `url_for`.

As a side note I have found that this flavour of srcset where you define the widths rather that the resolution orientated 1x, 1x method will result in a lot of server calls when you resize the window. Haven't found anything about this behaviour in the Rails docs.